# Autohotkey: How can I get the positions of win 7 desktop icons

Tags: autohotkey

I want to implement a poor mans "Windows Fences" (by stardock software) using autohotkey.

It can be as ineffective as it can as far as programming goes. I just want to get the positions of each desktop icon upon running a ahk code snippet and using another code snippet, I'd like to put them back to where they were.

I looked at the ahk code contributions and didn't see anything like this. But again, my search terms might be a little off. Assuming no such code exists, is there a way to get the screen positions of each icon and their identifying information in autohotkey ? This will at least help me start. I am sure more questions will come.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I am swamped at work and didn't have a time to try these suggeastions. As soon as I do, I will respond/contribute.

Answer (score 2):

## Example

Try the following with the function posted below :

```
icons := getDeskIconsPos()
chromePos := icons["Google Chrome"]
for k, pos in chromePos
{
        msgbox % "Google Chrome.lnk is at X: " pos.x " Y: " pos.y
}
```

## Description

The function returns an object (thanks to **MCL**) with each item being identified by name. Under each *name* item is an array of all occurring instances. Each array item will have an `X` and `Y` containing the corresponding coordinates.

See code for `THE_ITEMNAME`, `THE_X_COORD` and `THE_Y_COORD`.
I have used these names to clarify where the information is stored.

## The Function

```
getDeskIconsPos() {
    Critical
    static MEM_COMMIT := 0x1000, PAGE_READWRITE := 0x04, MEM_RELEASE := 0x8000
    static LVM_GETITEMPOSITION := 0x00001010, LVM_SETITEMPOSITION := 0x0000100F, WM_SETREDRAW := 0x000B

    ControlGet, hwWindow, HWND,, SysListView321, ahk_class Progman
    if !hwWindow ; #D mode
        ControlGet, hwWindow, HWND,, SysListView321, A
    IfWinExist ahk_id %hwWindow% ; last-found window set
        WinGet, iProcessID, PID
    hProcess := DllCall("OpenProcess"   , "UInt",   0x438           ; PROCESS-OPERATION|READ|WRITE|QUERY_INFORMATION
                                        , "Int",    FALSE           ; inherit = false
                                        , "ptr",    iProcessID)
    ret := {}
    if hwWindow and hProcess
    {  
        ControlGet, list, list,Col1
        VarSetCapacity(iCoord, 8)
        pItemCoord := DllCall("VirtualAllocEx", "ptr", hProcess, "ptr", 0, "UInt", 8, "UInt", MEM_COMMIT, "UInt", PAGE_READWRITE)
        Loop, Parse, list, `n ;Loop through items in list and get the information from the POINT structures
        {
            SendMessage, %LVM_GETITEMPOSITION%, % A_Index-1, %pItemCoord%
            DllCall("ReadProcessMemory", "ptr", hProcess, "ptr", pItemCoord, "UInt", &iCoord, "UInt", 8, "UIntP", cbReadWritten)

            ;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
            THE_ITEMNAME := A_LoopField
            THE_X_COORD := NumGet(iCoord,"Int")
            THE_Y_COORD := Numget(iCoord, 4,"Int")
            ;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
                        if(!ret.HasKey(THE_ITEMNAME))
                        {
                                ret[THE_ITEMNAME] := []
                        }
                        ret[THE_ITEMNAME].Insert({x: THE_X_COORD, y: THE_Y_COORD})
        }
        DllCall("VirtualFreeEx", "ptr", hProcess, "ptr", pItemCoord, "ptr", 0, "UInt", MEM_RELEASE)
    }
    DllCall("CloseHandle", "ptr", hProcess)
    return ret
}
```

## Extra

If you simply want to save and restore the desktop icon positions, you may try `DeskIcons()` here :
http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=3529

**Example** usage of `DeskIcons()` :

```
; save positions
coords := DeskIcons()
MsgBox now move the icons around yourself
; load positions
DeskIcons(coords)
```

Comment: Great work. I suggest using AHK_L's objects to eliminate the necessity of parsing the output string back into its components. I think that makes the function a lot easier to use. Have a look at my suggested changes: [http://pastebin.com/LBzRiH0z](http://pastebin.com/LBzRiH0z). It's untested but I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: nice idea! I didn't think of it. It works great, just a small typo on line 30 : `=` to `:=`. Bueno! ;)

Comment: You're right. Also, the clean initialization would be `ret := {}` since it's an object. Furthermore, using this "key-to-coordinates" association, there's a chance that multiple items with the same name will overwrite each other. I think using arrays for each item name would be the best solution. Check out this edit: [http://pastebin.com/jcPGDVbX](http://pastebin.com/jcPGDVbX).

Comment: +1 Right, good point. I imagine that files with no extension is a good example of this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy way to achieche this. But `ImageSearch` should work quite well if performance isn't an issue (even if it is: for smaller numbers of icons, it should still perform acceptably). The only problem I see is the desktop background: If it changes, `ImageSearch` will most likely fail, except for perfectly quadratic/nontransparent icons. There are three workarounds for that:

1. Never change your desktop background. The easiest way but most likely not an option if you are a frequent desktop restyler.
2. Take new screenshots of the icons every time you change the background. Very high maintenance depending on your need to change the desktop.
3. Let the script change the desktop background to a default color before it runs `ImageSearch`. My favorite since it's easy to implement and you won't have to worry about anything.

After you've found the position of the respective icon, the rest is pretty trivial: `MouseClickDrag` it from its old position to the target position.

### References:

- [ImageSearch
  docs](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm)
- [MouseClickDrag docs](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/MouseClickDrag.htm)
- [Changing the desktop background with AHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/47588-changing-desktop-background-wallpaper-windows-7/#entry296805)

Comment: Might be possible through COM with Dllcalls ... This sheds some light on it : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/18/10403054.aspx

Comment: @JoeDF Didn't know that it could be achievable without some kind of image recognition. Would you care to propose it as an answer?

Comment: Sure, Ill try to implement an example tonight. Ill post it as an answer when I can.

Comment: @JoeDF Way to go. It's always nice to see dedicated people actively contributing.

Comment: After much searching, i found this... http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/60982-deskicons-getset-desktop-icon-positions/ .. still checking

Comment: Okay, i have successfully fixed the function. here it is : http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=3529 I will now post an example.